# Meteor: Events in typeahead with multiple databases

Tags: javascript, meteor, twitter-typeahead

I'm using `sergeyt:typeahead` to add typeahead to my meteor app. And I'm using multiple databases. Now I need to get the select-event, but this doesn't work, as I can't use `teams` and `selected` together. So how do I get the select-event as I want to process the selected value?

```
Template.demo.helpers({
    teams: function(){
        return [
            {
                name: 'nba-teams',
                valueKey: 'name',
                local: function() { return Nba.find().fetch(); },
                header: '<h3 class="league-name">NBA Teams</h3>',
                template: 'team'
            },
            {
                name: 'nhl-teams',
                valueKey: 'name',
                local: function() { return Nhl.find().fetch(); },
                header: '<h3 class="league-name">NHL Teams</h3>',
                template: 'team'
            }
        ];
    },
    selected: function(event, suggestion, datasetName) {
        console.log(suggestion.id);
    }
});
```

**Template**

```
<template name="demo">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control typeahead" name="team" type="text"
           placeholder="NBA and NHL teams"
           autocomplete="off" spellcheck="off"
           data-sets="teams"
           data-selected="selected"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add `data-selected="selected"` as an attribute in your input tag:

```
<input class="form-control typeahead" name="team" type="text"
       placeholder="NBA and NHL teams"
       autocomplete="off" spellcheck="off"
       data-sets="teams" data-selected="selected" />
```

Also, the name of your template (demo) doesn't match the name of the template to which you're adding the helpers (multiple_datasets).

Comment: I corrected these two points in my code, but it still doesn't work.